# Issue with grid cross validation in decision tree regressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Let's assume that I have defined a regressor like that

```py
tree = MultiOutputRegressor(DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0))
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And now I want to do a grid cross validation to optimize the parameter `ccp_alpha` (I don't know if it is the best parameter to optimize but I take it as example). Thus I do it like that:

```py
alphas = np.arange(0,2,0.1)
pipe_tree = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler), ('pca', pca), ('tree', tree)], memory = 'tmp')
treeCV = GridSearchCV(pipe_tree, dict( pca__n_components=n_components, tree__ccp_alpha=alphas ), cv=5, scoring ='r2', n_jobs=-1)

start_time = time.time()
treeCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The problem is that I take this issue:

```py
ValueError: Invalid parameter ccp_alpha for estimator Pipeline(memory='tmp',
         steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA()),
                ('tree',
                 MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

If I use the command `tree.get_params().keys()` it prints a list of possible parameters to change in my model. I think the problem is this `tree__ccp_alpha=alphas` in `GridSearchCV()` command. But whatever change I do, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is `tree` in your post, but it seems like a multipleregressor on top of your decision tree. If you set that up correctly it should work. First we define the params:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np

alphas = np.arange(0,2,0.1)
n_components = [3,4,5]
```

Then set up the steps:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA()
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
tree = MultiOutputRegressor(DecisionTreeClassifier())
```

Toy data:

```
X_train = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,10))
y_train = np.random.binomial(1,0.5,(100,2))
```

Pipeline:

```
pipe_tree = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler), ('pca', pca), ('tree', tree)])
tree.get_params()

{'estimator__ccp_alpha': 0.0,
 'estimator__class_weight': None,
 'estimator__criterion': 'gini',
 'estimator__max_depth': None,
 'estimator__max_features': None,
 'estimator__max_leaf_nodes': None,
 'estimator__min_impurity_decrease': 0.0,
 'estimator__min_impurity_split': None,
 'estimator__min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'estimator__min_samples_split': 2,
 'estimator__min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0,
 'estimator__presort': 'deprecated',
 'estimator__random_state': None,
 'estimator__splitter': 'best',
 'estimator': DecisionTreeClassifier(),
 'n_jobs': None}
```

The param should be `estimator__ccp_alpha`. So if we append `tree` before it, with `tree__estimator__ccp_alpha = alphas` it works:

```
treeCV = GridSearchCV(pipe_tree, dict( pca__n_components=n_components, tree__estimator__ccp_alpha=alphas ),
                      cv=5, scoring ='r2', n_jobs=-1)
treeCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If I use yours:

```
treeCV = GridSearchCV(pipe_tree, dict( pca__n_components=n_components, tree__ccp_alpha=alphas ),
                      cv=5, scoring ='r2', n_jobs=-1)
```

I get the same error